# Is that normal to have "mini contracts" after meetings?

Tags: contracts

I work as a public school teacher in the USA. More and more frequently, my supervisors have been creating little documents for us to sign, usually after a meeting and presentation, often agreeing we'll complete some tasks described in the presentation, such as that we'll pass on particular information to students, enforce certain kinds of student behavior. This is at my school only, so this isn't coming from the government. I'm not given a choice to not sign them.

Is that typical to be given "mini contracts" throughout the year? How can I politely refuse to sign without people causing me trouble?

Comment: No. It's not normal. I don't work in the education sector however. You never have to sign anything that you don't want to, but I get your point.

Comment: “Thanks, but I’d rather not sign that.”

Comment: You can politely refuse, but people will cause you troubles regardless.

Comment: I think, though, that regardless of how "polite" you are in your refusal, your supervisor will see it as an act of insubordination and will treat you accordingly. Maybe you could discuss with your fellow teachers before the next meeting and see if you can convince others to refuse to sign as well. It might strengthen your position if you're not the only one.

Comment: Let me flip that around Joe and ask what is the benefit of signing _for the supervisor_? Why do they want this paper trail? What are the consequences for the OP if, for any reason, one of the statements in the mini-contract can't be delivered? It smells like a setup. Do not sign.

Comment: Never sign anything that doesnt benefit you as well as obligate you.

Comment: @WesleyLong Continued employment could be considered a killer benefit.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the administration wants to cover itselves whenever new policies/proceedures are wanted/needed to be put into the operations/syllabus. Via those mini-contracts they want to get some sort of legal grip on their teachers/staff in order to deflect responsibilities.

In case other public schools in your state/province are following a similar strategy, I would presume that this is something ordinary and covered by your local laws (keep in mind IANAL).

But since you state

> This is at my school only, so this isn't coming from the government.

and ask:

> Is that typical to be given "mini contracts" throughout the year?

IMO this would raise a flag (as it obviously raised one with you) and I would consult the [AFT](https://www.aft.org/) (American Federation of teachers) or similar organisations/unions that can clarifiy the reasons and legality of such *mini-contracts*.

In regards to:

> How can I politely refuse to sign without people causing me trouble?

I'd keep it with the statements in the comments:

*“Thanks, but I’d rather not sign that.”*

*"You can politely refuse, but people will cause you troubles regardless.*

I personally disagree with Joe's comment (whos advices I regularly agree with and appreciate reading),

*"Why not sign? What benefit do you see in not signing? What do you think you can avoid by not signing? Are you imagining that you won't be required to do what the supervisor wants, if you choose not to sign?"*

since signing any document shouldn't be taken lighthearted nor should anyone feel obliged to do so unless there's a legal reasoning, an operational proceedure or other certain and valid *needs* behind it.

Comment: I think you meant the AFT, not the ATF.

Comment: If you are a member of a teachers' union talk to your union rep and ask how to handle this.  Or politely ask your department head or principal "what's up with these mini-contracts? I've always kept my word about my work."

Comment: @cpast Thanks for the hint! ;) - I'll edit my answer accordingly..

Answer (score 4):

> Is that typical to be given "mini contracts" throughout the year?

No, it's not. It's a red flag. But not necessarily for you. Nobody *likes* paperwork. Your boss at that school certainly has better things to do than create those documents, collect the signatures and store them for later. It's not his secret passion. They do that for a reason.

The most likely reason is that someone should have been disciplined for something and claimed they did not know better. Despite this claim being obviously wrong, they could not be disciplined because "obviously wrong" is not proof of anything and the force protecting them, whether it's a lawyer, trade union representative or mistaken HR department needs *proof*. So now they are creating proof for the next time, so this does not happen again. That's tedious, but the only way to make the paper-pushers happy.

<sup>Sidenote: we had a post here on how someone claimed they did not know you are not supposed to take things from your employer that were meant for a customer for your own personal gain. So without the fancy words: they claimed nobody ever told them to not steal from your employer. If that is a valid defense in whatever legal battle, then the only recourse the employer has is document *everything*, every little thing they do. That is how your mini contracts come into being. Needing written proof of the things that most people consider normal.</sup>

Good thing is: if you have not been in discussions about you being disciplined and you haven't claimed you didn't know better, this is not about you. You are just signing those things because they are not allowed to single out a specific person to sign everything they are told. So you are an innocent bystander to their actual target.